# Производительность команд < и <=

Tags: c++, ассемблер

Давно мучаюсь вопросом есть ли различия между командами меньше и меньше или равно на низком уровне в плане количества команд и производительности?

То есть на машинном коде меньше или равно это две команды подряд, а меньше одна? Или они обе представляют собой одну команду?
Без учета выгрузки из памяти значений и т.п. Просто сами по себе.

Comment: Компилятор может скомпилировать код так, что там вообще не будет явной проверки. А если и использует - то команды `JL` и `JLE` вряд ли отличаются по производительности.

Comment: Почти во всех CPU это одна команда. Время выполнения одинаковое.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Операторы языка С++ и машинные команды - это два разных, никак однозначно не связанных друг с другом мира. Поэтому абстрактно рассуждать о "производительности" операторов языка в терминах команд низкого уровня (т.е. машинных команд) - совершенно бесполезная и бессмысленная задача. Между этими мирами нет никакого однозначного соответствия. Невозможно предсказать, в какие машинные команды будут странслированы операторы `<` и `<=` в каждом конкретном контексте кода (даже одним и тем же компилятором, даже с одними и теми же настройками).

Это не говоря уже о том, что во многих популярных машинных архитектурах (читай: наш родной x86) вообще нет монолитных машинных команд, соответствующих встроенным операторам `<` и `<=`. Сравнения обычно выливаются в двухэтапную операцию:

1. Выставление флагов состояния процессора на основе сравнения операндов
2. Конкретное действие, зависящее от этих флагов (условный переход, формирование булевского значения, и т.п.)

И способ формирования флагов состояния процессора, и последующее действие зависят от конкретного кода, использующего `<` и `<=`. Например, выставление флагов состояния процессора может быть бесплатным наследием предыдущей машинной операции, формировавшей операнды для сравнения. В такой ситуации первый этап выполнять не надо вообще.

Answer (score 1):

Все условные переходы выполняются единственной командой из семейства команд `Jcc`. Конкретно по вашему вопросу, переход по "меньше" это команда `JL`, а по "меньше или равно" - команда `JLE`. Семейство это большое, даже огромное - несколько десятков команд, но все они выполняются за одно и то же время. Исключением являются несколько команд которые совмещают проверку условия и переход, например `JECXZ`, которая проверяет содержимое регистра ECX, и выполняет переход если не 0. Эти команды выполняются чуть медленнее, чем обычные условные переходы.

На всякий случай еще скажу, что команды условных переходов (за исключением `JCXZ/JECXZ`) ничего не анализируют, а просто выполняют или не выполняют переход в зависимости от состояния флагов в регистре флагов. Сами флаги, такие как `Zero`, `Sign`, `Carry`и т.д., устанавливаются предыдущей операцией. Это может быть как операция сравнения, так и например, арифметическая. Например, после команды вычитания `SUB` можно сразу поставить команду `JZ` "переход если 0", потому что `SUB` устанавливает флаги и дополнительной команды сравнения не требуется.